# Как получить имя скрипта?

Tags: python

Всем привет, есть файл "main.pу", но если его переименовать к примеру "main1.py", то работать он уже естественно не будет.
Суть в том что мне нужно чтобы python файл мог узнавать своё имя, Помогите узнать как это сделать?

Comment: Почему «работать он уже естественно не будет»? Зачем ему узнавать своё имя?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без никаких библиотек:

```
print(__file__.split('\\')[-1])
```

Универсальное предложение от `Evrik`:

```
from os.path import sep
print(__file__.split(sep)[-1])
```

Comment: В macOS и Linux будет работать некорректно

Comment: если только всё-таки добавить библиотеку и сплитить по `os.path.sep`

Answer (score 1):

Данный код выводит название скрипта. Засуньте `os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])` в переменную и используйте её в своих целях

```
import os
import sys

print(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))
```